# Make selected text in Notes the default style (no custom fonts, colors, bold, underline etc)

Tags: macos, notes.app

I'd like to be able to select some text in Notes and hit a key or something to make that selected text go "default". No bolds, italics, fonts, or big/small sizes. Is there any such feature?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no clear formatting option or shortcut, however you can copy and paste the formatting of selected text.

For example if you have a note open with normal formatting, even just opening a new note and typing hello, press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the default normal formatting, then select the note you want to clear and press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste that formatting over the text (i.e. clear the formatting).

Also as a point of note, typically you only get these issues from copying and pasting from a formatted document. You can avoid this by using `Paste and Match Style` which is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Hope that helps!